# Python: product as the range step

Tags: python

I want to get a list of num like 10,100,1000,10000...
I can do this by Java using the following code:

```
for (int i = 10;i<100001;i*=10){
    .....
}
```

How can I implement this by Python?

```
for i in range(what?)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to turn the normally additive `range()` into an exponent:

```
for i in (10**x for x in range(1,6)):
```

Answer (score 1):

`range` doesn't have that capability. You could just use a `while` loop, or `10 ** i for i in xrange(7)`.